# What does Fate do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I just found a sad/dead blue head (called "Fate" when I picked it up), and now I have half of a white heart (*not* a soul heart) and wings.

What does Fate do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heart becomes a permanent one after you beat that level without taking any damage. The wings are permanent and let you cross ravines and spikes without taking damage.

Comment: Are wings and the white heart the only effects from Fate?

Comment: @IanPugsley yes, Fate does only that, which is anyway better than, let's say, Transcendence, that only makes you fly