# What are the white hearts?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

Apparently multiple items can give you white hearts, like the ones given by [Fate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/what-does-fate-do).

What are these white hearts? What do they do, and what can give them to you?

Comment: I got a white heart as a room drop once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

White hearts (which [the wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Hearts#Eternal_Hearts) calls Eternal Hearts) sit above regular hearts, but below soul hearts in the order of what takes damage first. When you fill up a white heart or you go down a level with half a white heart, it turns into a heart container.

According to the [mechanics guide](https://gist.github.com/dpatti/4419061#hearts), any regular heart drop has a 1/50 chance of becoming an eternal heart. This excludes hearts from the Bloody Penny or Little C.H.A.D., which are always half hearts. In addition, in the super secret room that contains a single eternal heart, any other regular heart drop in that room automatically becomes an eternal heart.

Comment: Gold treasure chests can also spawn them.

Comment: You can also get them from beggars, and Chapel rooms.

Comment: Just got one from a pile of poop as well!

Comment: @mordi2k wow, I'm surprised. Poop drops are usually really minor.

Comment: Indeed, guess I got lucky with a very rare drop :p

Comment: @murgatroid99 actually it can randomly replace any heart or half-heart drop. In addition to all the drops you report, I got one also from a slot machine with the "three hearts" combination.

Answer (score 0):

Also, picking up an Eternal Heart while already having one will instantly turn that into a heart container, consuming the Heart you just picked up.